# Git always asks for username and password on one of three computers. The other two don't ask. How do I find the reason?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have three computers A, B, and C.  I can ssh between any two with no password required.  From A and B I can push a commit to GitHub without being asked for name or password.  On C it always asks for both.  I have done ssh git@github.com and I get the message that I have been authenticated, but, of course, it doesn't support command line access.  I have copied the same .gitconfig file from A to B and to C to be sure they are using the same username, key access file, and helper.  I copied the .ssh/id_rsa.pub file contents and added that as a ssh key on GitHub in my account.

I am puzzled and don't know what to look at next.  Is there another setting or configuration that I am missing?

Comment: What are the differences in the `.git/config` in the working copies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first your remote URL on C:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote -v
```

If you see an URL starting with HTTPS, then it is possible the credential helper (git config credential.helper) is not set, hence the request for a username/password.
SSH would not be involved at all.

You can also switch back to an SSH URL on C:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote set-url origin git@github.com/<you>/<yourRepo>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really puzzling. I checked git config --edit on A and B and the credential was helper = store.  On C there wasn't one.  I did git config --edit on C and added the [credential] / helper = store and voila!  It now works.